# Lorentz invariant but baryon number violating operators from a single fermion field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions

In a theory of a single fermion, is it possible to write down a Lagrangian that violates the global U(1) symmetry (e.g. baryon number) but that is Lorenz invariant? 
I'm wondering because the only Hermition Lorentz invariant in spin $1/2$ theory I'm aware of is $\bar{\psi} \psi=\psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \psi$, which is manifestly invariant under $U(1)$.

Comment: Sure you can, one example is $\psi_L \psi_L$, also known as a Majorana mass.

Comment: related: [Is it possible to have renormalisable C-, P-, or T-violating terms in QED?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361331/84967).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Lorentz invariant operator $C$ including the complex conjugation operator $K$. The desired operator is
$$
\mathcal{L}_{M} = m\bar{\psi}C\psi
$$ 
Writing this operator as $C = AK$, where $A$ is some matrix, the requirement of the Lorentz invariance translates into
$$
A\Sigma_{\mu\nu}^{*} = \Sigma_{\mu\nu}A,
$$
where $\Sigma_{\mu\nu} \sim [\gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}]$ is the generator of the Lorentz group transformations for the Dirac representations of the Lorentz group.

The answer, of course, depends on the choice of the $\gamma$ matrices basis. In the Weyl basis (and for any basis related to it by the real transformation) you need to note the simple identity
$$
\gamma_{2}\Sigma_{\mu\nu}^{*}\gamma_{2} = -\Sigma_{\mu\nu},
$$ 
which means that $A = \gamma_{2}$.

The operator $C = \gamma_{2}K$ coincides with the charge conjugation operator. The spinor $\psi_{M} = \psi + C\psi$ is the analog of real objects in the space of the Dirac spinors and is called the Majorana spinor.